# I have an error when creating the apk with buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

```
[DEBUG]:    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
[DEBUG]:    make: *** [Makefile:614: sharedmods] Error 1
[DEBUG]:    make: se sale del directorio '/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
Exception in thread background thread for pid 4595:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j 4 -C /home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build

  STDOUT:
make: se entra en el directorio '/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
 CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared    ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall'  _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS=''   ./python -E /home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/setup.py  build
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:17: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
  warnings.warn(
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:30: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/subprocess.py", line 64, in <module>
    import msvcrt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from distutils import log
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _distutils_hack.override  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/override.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('_distutils_hack').do_override()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 71, in do_override
    ensure_local_distutils()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 58, in ensure_local_distutils
    core = importlib.import_module('distutils.core')
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 17, in <module>
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/util.py", line 14, in <module>
    from distutils.spawn import spawn
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/spawn.py", line 11, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/subprocess.py", line 69, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
make: *** [Makefile:614: sharedmods] Error 1
make: se sale del directorio '/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1276, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 725, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 580, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/hostpython3/__init__.py", line 113, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.make, '-j', str(cpu_count()), '-C', build_dir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 953, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 879, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.2-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j 4 -C /home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build

  STDOUT:
make: se entra en el directorio '/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'
 CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared    ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall'  _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS=''   ./python -E /home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/setup.py  build
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:17: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools, but importing Setuptools also replaces the `distutils` module in `sys.modules`. This may lead to undesirable behaviors or errors. To avoid these issues, avoid using distutils directly, ensure that setuptools is installed in the traditional way (e.g. not an editable install), and/or make sure that setuptools is always imported before distutils.
  warnings.warn(
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:30: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/subprocess.py", line 64, in <module>
    import msvcrt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from distutils import log
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _distutils_hack.override  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/override.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('_distutils_hack').do_override()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 71, in do_override
    ensure_local_distutils()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 58, in ensure_local_distutils
    core = importlib.import_module('distutils.core')
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 17, in <module>
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/util.py", line 14, in <module>
    from distutils.spawn import spawn
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/spawn.py", line 11, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/subprocess.py", line 69, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
make: *** [Makefile:614: sharedmods] Error 1
make: se sale del directorio '/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build'


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu-laptop:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1226,unix/ubuntu-laptop:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1226'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     NVM_INC = '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/include/node'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LANGUAGE = 'es_NI:es'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1182'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/ubuntu/code/python/kivy'
#     LOGNAME = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/ubuntu'
#     USERNAME = 'ubuntu'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'es_NI.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/a126cb99_0ce2_4e82_af39_8ae93f5d0246'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '04dc41e41a1445ed91e9e264e142e759'
#     MANAGERPID = '890'
#     NVM_DIR = '/home/ubuntu/.nvm'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.122'
#     MAVEN_HOME = '/opt/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     NVM_CD_FLAGS = ''
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=fe5e8e17321a52c3bb462a3b61ef3634'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:33612'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/:/opt/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=fe5e8e17321a52c3bb462a3b61ef3634'
#     NVM_BIN = '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/bin'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I have an error when creating the apk with buildozer help me ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

Comment: I have the exact same error. Would be glad to solve.

Comment: Mention 
What command you executed?
What research have you done to resolve this issue?
And remove unwanted special characters "*"

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling an older version of setuptools worked for me.

1. `pip3 uninstall setuptools && pip3 install setuptools=58.0.0`
2. `pip3 list | grep setuptools` to check if 58.0.0 is really
   installed.

After downgrading setuptools, be sure that you really installed an older version than the previous one.
To see more about this issue: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1391